# Cannot debug depended Project, always returns error if the Project that depends on it is not build

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm really clueless and confused as to use which keyword for asking this question, so please read description first,

I have a solution with multiple projects, Say that there's Project A, then I created Project B that depended on Project A, now I need to change something in Project A, when I tried debugging Project A (after setting it as Startup Project), somehow Project B always pops out, and when I clean the Project B, every time I tried to Debug Project A, it will throw an Error saying

"Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program 'xxxxxxx/ProjectB.exe'. The system cannot find the file specified."

What property or file should I check, I tried looking for any wrong dependencies from Project A to B, but I don't find anything suspicious.

Comment: Is Project A a library or an executable program?

Comment: Please check your build order. Right click your solution -> 'build order'. Please also check the dependecies tab in the same window.

Comment: @ikkentim Both of them is some kind of a console project, they're both for Web API.

Comment: @nilSK For Project A the build order seems to be ok, the project B is left on the lowest order of build.

Comment: sorry for the late response ... hope you had a nice weekend :s
Im a bit confused by your setup. Maybe i got you wrong? Project A is your starting project, right? Why is project B dependen on A? Normaly you have a starting project, that knows about the class library project, that does not know about it's starting project. E.g.: FancyToolsProject is started by FancyTollsProject.Console. That way you could use FancyTools by lets say FancyToolsProject.WindowsForms too. Maybe your project structure is the problem?

Comment: @nilsK Thanks, maybe it is a bit weird, Project A has DB Model (edmx) that Project B wants to use, that's why B depended on A. I know, maybe the DB should've been a separate project, but I'm new on this project and so is Project B, for now I have to make do for some things.